# Symfony2 - what is the best way to perform an external swagger based web service

Tags: php, rest, api, symfony, swagger

I have a **rest web service description** based on [**Swagger api framework**](http://swagger.io/) and i would like to use this external web service on my **symfony2** project.

many suggestion for this problem :

- Using cURL like this [exemple](https://themekraft.com/getting-json-data-with-php-curl/)
- Using Bundles like [ChRist ClientBundle](https://github.com/CircleOfNice/CiRestClientBundle) or [Guzzle Bundle](https://github.com/8p/GuzzleBundle)
- Writing a service to manage the external call.

what is the best way to use this web service ? and can 'i use the php client generated by **[swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io/#/)** ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Personally I used Guzzle Bundle and it should works